# Colorbox opens at the wrong size, then shrinks to correct size

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a web page with several links that open Colorboxes. All of the links work correctly except one. The problem link works fine in most respects, but when the colorbox opens, it does so larger than is specified in the parameters, then shrinks to the correct size.

I found a similar problem on the web (can't recall if it was on Stackoverflow) that was solved by making sure that the colorbox css file loaded prior to the script. I did this, but it made no difference.

Of the various colorboxes on the page, this is the only one that contains a form or does any ajax stuff. That's probably not relevant, but it's the only real difference I can see between this colorbox and the other ones that work fine.

The code for the link is: `<a href="notifyList.cgi?bibId={$bibId}" rel="notifyMe" id="notifyFormLink">Notify Me</a>`

The jQuery code is pasted below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
                    $(function(){
                        $('#notifyFormLink').colorbox({
                                width:300,
                                height:270,
                                opacity:0,
                                transition:"none",
                                scrolling:false,
                                onComplete: function() {
                                    notifySubmit();
                                }}); // end colorbox
                    }); // end anon function                        

                    function notifySubmit() {
                        // $.colorbox.resize();
                        $('#emailNotify').focus();
                        $("#notifyForm").submit(function(){
                            var input = $('#emailNotify').val();
                            if (input.match(/^[\w\d\.\+]+@[\w\d\.\+]+$/)) {
                                $.get(
                                    $(this).attr('action'),
                                    $(this).serialize(),
                                    function(data){
                                        $().colorbox({
                                            html: data,
                                            width:300,
                                            height:270,
                                            opacity:0,
                                            transition:"none",
                                            scrolling:false,
                                            onComplete: function() {
                                                notifySubmit();
                                                }});
                                            } // end data
                                        ); // end get
                                        return false;
                            } else {
                                $('#validationResponse').html('<span style="font-size:12px">Bad e-mail: please try again.</span>');
                                return false;       
                            }
                         }); // end submit 
                    } // end notifySubmit
```

Comment: Interesting issue, and great sample code, btw.  Assume you've tried initialHeight and initialWidth parameters? Also, why use a REL attribute if you're binding by ID?

Comment: Many thanks, Kevin! I had not tried the initialHeight and initialWidth parameters. I find that if I use these in combination with innerHeight and innerWidth (rather than the regular height and width parameters), the colorboxes appear at the correct size and stay that way. Again, thanks so much for helping me get past this frustrating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the answer was to use the initialHieght and initialWidth properties in conjunction with innerHeight and innerWidth in this use case.